# overlapping problem with checkboxes in materialize

Tags: html, css, checkbox, materialize

I have built a website that is a quiz and designed it with "Materialize".
Now I have the problem that the texts of the answers overwrite each other. The distance between the checkboxes always stays the same, no matter how long the text is.

[Here is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xgJc6.png)

The following is my code

```
<html><head><title>Coding Project 2</title>

    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 form-box">
            <h3 class="center-align">Coding Project 2</h3>
            <form method="post">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <span><b>Question 1:</b> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" id="question" name="question" value="TWO16">
                                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ans_a" id="ans_a" value="A">
                                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ans_b" id="ans_b" value="B">
                                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="input-field col s12">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="ans_c" id="ans_c" value="C">
                                <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam</span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                                                                                    <br><br>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s6">
                        <a class="btn red" href="https://example.com/try.php?cancel">Cancel</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s6 right-align">
                        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit" name="submitu" id="submitu">next<i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </form></div>
    </div>    
<!--JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js">
</script>
</div></body></html>
```

Can anyone help me?

I have already tried to change the height manually several times, but I don't want the answers to always be of different lengths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the text contents automatically fit the height, Please

(1) change all the

```
<label>xxxxx
</label>
```

to

```
<div><label>xxxxx</label></div>
```

and

(2) Change

```
<span>xxxx</span>
```

to

```
<span style="height:auto;">xxxx</span>
```

For your case, you need to change 3 occurrences (you have 3 answers)

You may view the result in the sandbox here:

https://www.createchhk.com/SOanswers/testSO23Aug2023.html

Comment: Thanks.
The text is still overlapped in the mobile version of the website.
or if I reduce the width of the page

Comment: Please see my slighly revised answer addressing the issue of mobile version / responsive layout

Comment: The text now fits. But, you can no longer use the checkboxes now. :/

Comment: Please see my further revised answer and try the revised sandbox link (we have to, in some way, override some strange behaviors of Materialize)